# Can I use Emulex LP9802DC-E Dual Channel PCI-X host bus adapter to replace failed LP9002DC-E?

Tags: hardware, hba, pci, emulex

One LP9002DC-E HBA card has failed, and I have trouble finding an exact replacement. However, I was able to find a supplier for LP9802DC-E. From what I can understand on paper, the only substantial difference is that LP9002DC-E uses 66MHz PCI-X, and LP9802DC-E supports 133MHz PCI-X (but is backwards compatible with 66MHz).
So from what I can see now, it should be safe to use LP9802DC-E as a replacement. Can anyone comment on that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably [search for the card you need on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=LP9002DC-E&_from=R40&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.TRS0&_nkw=LP9002DC-E&_sacat=0)... I mean, we're talking about equipment that can be obtained for $10 today... You may as well replace it with the same thing.

I'm afraid to ask what it's connected to, because 2Gb Fibre-channel and PCI-X are *really* old technologies and you're probably keeping the server/storage running on life-support...

Best of luck.

[image]

Comment: I understand that, but shipping takes time, and I can get LP9802DC-E tomorrow. So back to the original question?

Comment: Okay. Go for it.